# Stick a div with Sticky-kit and release it in an specific point in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sticky

I have a webpage with two columns. I want to stick a div in the left column  until the user scrolls down to an specific end of an element in the right column. I´m trying to use the Jquery library Sticky-kit http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ . I´m able to stick the div, but I cannot release it when I hit the end of the element of the right column. The Jquery code is inside an AngularJS directive (although I think it doesn´t affect to the problem).

Find a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6tT6408OY530b6hYflDL?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="column-one">
        <div sticky class="stick">
          <map latitude="39.65" longitude="3.0175" zoom="8" class="map-container" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 20px"></map>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column-two">
        <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
        <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <h3 id="release-stick">I WANT TO RELEASE THE STICKY COLUMN AT THE END OF THIS ELEMENT</h3>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.welcome = "Hello, testing sticky!" ;
});

app.directive('sticky', function() {    
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {          

        console.log("Sticky directive has been called!");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //var elParent = $("#release-sticky");    
            console.log("Sticky tries to get parent!");              
            var options = {/*parent: elParent,*/ bottoming: false};         
            $(".stick").stick_in_parent(options); 
        });                                               
    };

    return {        
        link: link
    };
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.column-one {width: 40%; float:left; margin-right: 20px}
.column-two {width: 50%; float:right; margin-right: 20px}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with the code. First of all, considering you are using floats, you need to add an element with `clear` property at the end of the `#release-sticky` (or use a css `clearfix`). So basically something like:

```
<div id="release-sticky" class="container">
  ...contents...
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

The reason behind this is that when you use floats, and don't clear afterwards, the browser doesnt allocate height for the parent. (so basically your `#release-sticky` has 0 height).

Secondly, there appears to be some kind of error when using the bottoming option. Removing it seems to fix the problems :)

Lastly, there is no need for $(document).ready() since, as AngularJS docs state:

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'.

Also, i changed the element that had sticky class but just for display purposes, it works just as well if you revert the change (it just has no border then).

Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/h3ws1pckAHxk9T0JlnMJ?p=preview

Comment: Do you know how can I keep always a space or margin between the stuck element and the elements below him? See updated plunked: https://plnkr.co/edit/Nz9UVWs055y7rvFO53Aw?p=preview

Comment: Not entirely sure what do you mean.

Comment: If you see the new plunker in my comment. There is a margin-bottom: 20px below the sticky Google Maps. However, when you scroll up this margin dissapears  with the content below de map. I want to scroll that content but keeping the margin or whatever space in white between both elements.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t see the changes... did you save them? I have updated the column name for clarification. It should be always a margin/padding between the map and the 'Sticky Navigation Example column 2'.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally copied the wrong plunk, https://plnkr.co/edit/92VZYuvU1SqI7xsMdxcj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works perfect in the plunker. For sure, it´s right and looks pretty easy, however it´s not working in my code and I don´t know what is it? My code and plunker are not exactly the same. Do you think can be related to bootstrap2.3.2? I have a position: relative and overflow:hidden in the map...

Comment: I have created a new post to keep the problems clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508604/stick-a-div-with-sticky-kit-and-release-it-in-an-specific-point-in-angularjs-par