# Stick a div with Sticky-kit and release it in an specific point in AngularJS part II

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

This is a extension of this post I have created to keep problems separated and clear: [Stick a div with Sticky-kit and release it in an specific point in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461046/stick-a-div-with-sticky-kit-and-release-it-in-an-specific-point-in-angularjs)

The point is the post works perfectly in plunkers. However, not working in my code which is not exactly the same.

I´m using bootstrap 2.3.2 (I think it´s not the problem). This is my real code:

```
<div id="sticky-parent" class="row-fluid custom-row-margin-20">     

        <!-- boats side -->
        <div id="boats-top" class="span8">  
          ...                                               
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div sticky class="stick">
                <!-- This is a directive that loads a Google Map -->
                <boats-map location="Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España" latitude="39.65" longitude="3.12" zoom="8" class="map-container boats-map-container"></boats-map>  
                 <div ng-include src="'partials/filters.html'"></div>                                                       
            </div>                                                      
        </div>              
</div>
```

Some considerations:
1. I´m not using the  suggested in the previous post. Aparently it´s working without it.
2. The problem comes when I try to have a padding-bottom: 20px in the map, so the div below always scrolls up with some space. What I have noticed is, when I add:

```
<div sticky class="stick">
   <!-- This is a directive that loads a Google Map -->
   <boats-map location="Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España" latitude="39.65" longitude="3.12" zoom="8" class="map-container boats-map-container"></boats-map>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 20px; background: #f5f5f5"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div sticky class="stick">
   <div style="padding-bottom: 20px; background: #f5f5f5">
      <!-- This is a directive that loads a Google Map -->
      <boats-map location="Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España" latitude="39.65" longitude="3.12" zoom="8" class="map-container boats-map-container"></boats-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

The padding is included, but the sticky stop working.

In the other hand, if I just comment the boats-map directive, the code works as expected. Like this:

```
<div sticky class="stick"><div>Hello</div>
    <!--<boats-map location="Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España" latitude="39.65" longitude="3.12" zoom="8" class="map-container boats-map-container"></boats-map>-->
    <div class="test-stick"></div>                                          
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I include the html generated:

```
<div sticky="" class="stick">
  <div location="Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España" latitude="39.65" longitude="3.12" zoom="8" style="height: 200px !important;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
      <div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px;"><div tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; cursor: url(&quot;http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;) 8 8, default;"><div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 396px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 652px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 652px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 396px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 396px; top: 313px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 652px; top: 313px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 908px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 313px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 908px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 908px; top: 313px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 140px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -116px; top: 57px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -116px; top: 313px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -116px; top: -199px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: 313px;"></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 1264px; height: 446px;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&amp;1i7796&amp;2i6087&amp;2e1&amp;3u6&amp;4m2&amp;1u1264&amp;2u446&amp;5m5&amp;1e0&amp;5ses&amp;6sus&amp;10b1&amp;12b1&amp;token=80826" style="width: 1264px; height: 446px;"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 396px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i32!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=105826" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 652px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i33!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=104057" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 652px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i33!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=30173" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 652px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i33!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=87360" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 396px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i32!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=31942" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i31!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=50408" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 908px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i34!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=85591" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i31!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=107595" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 908px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i34!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=11707" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 140px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i31!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107377!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=85632" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i35!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=9938" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -116px; top: 57px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i30!3i24!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107185!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=21887" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -116px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i30!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107185!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=79074" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -116px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i30!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107125!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=93996" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: 313px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i35!3i25!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=67125" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 396px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i32!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=48639" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 908px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i34!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=28404" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 1164px; top: -199px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i35!3i23!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i409107401!3m9!2ses!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=83822" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-pbc" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0;"><p class="gm-style-pbt"></p></div><div style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div></div></div><div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=38.16684,5.190923&amp;z=6&amp;t=m&amp;hl=es&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Haz clic aquí para visualizar esta zona en Google Maps" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"><div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4_hdpi.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></a></div><div style="background-color: white; padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 148px; position: absolute; left: 482px; top: 133px;"><div style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 16px;">Datos de mapas</div><div style="font-size: 13px;">Datos de mapas ©2018 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google, Inst. Geogr. Nacional, ORION-ME</div><div style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;"><img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 86px; bottom: 0px; width: 424px;"><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: none;">Datos de mapas</a><span style="">Datos de mapas ©2018 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google, Inst. Geogr. Nacional, ORION-ME</span></div></div></div><div class="gmnoscreen" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); direction: ltr; text-align: right; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">Datos de mapas ©2018 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google, Inst. Geogr. Nacional, ORION-ME</div></div><div class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc" draggable="false" style="z-index: 1000001; user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/es_US/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Términos de uso</a></div></div><div style="cursor: pointer; width: 25px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; display: none; margin: 10px 14px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;"><img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/sv9.png" draggable="false" class="gm-fullscreen-control" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -86px; width: 164px; height: 175px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: none;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a target="_new" title="Informar a Google acerca de errores en las imágenes o en el mapa de carreteras" href="https://www.google.com/maps/@38.1668403,5.1909229,6z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&amp;rapsrc=apiv3" style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; position: relative;">Informar de un error de Maps</a></div></div><div class="gmnoprint gm-bundled-control gm-bundled-control-on-bottom" draggable="false" controlwidth="28" controlheight="55" style="margin: 10px; user-select: none; position: absolute; bottom: 69px; right: 28px;"><div class="gmnoprint" controlwidth="28" controlheight="55" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div draggable="false" style="user-select: none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 28px; height: 55px;"><div title="Acerca la imagen" aria-label="Acerca la imagen" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; width: 28px; height: 27px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px; left: 7px; top: 6px;"><img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl_hdpi.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 120px; height: 54px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 67%; height: 1px; left: 16%; background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230); top: 0px;"></div><div title="Aleja la imagen" aria-label="Aleja la imagen" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; width: 28px; height: 27px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px; left: 7px; top: 6px;"><img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl_hdpi.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -15px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 120px; height: 54px;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
  <div class="test-stick"></div>                                            
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand you. Please see the examples above, it´s like that.

Comment: The map on scroll is supposed to cover the div with filters?

Comment: There should be a right column (span4). Inside of it, first there is the map and below it (supposely with a padding: 20px) another div with filters. The map should not cover anything but itself... if I understand you.

Comment: Yes. But with the padding.